# When using Angular 5 routerLink for routing, home slider or google maps in contact component is not loading

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a static website using angular 5,i am using owl carousel as image slider.I have implemented routing, after clicking on home menu slider not showing, only showing when page are loading for first time.
Below is my code

**navigation.component.html**

```
   <div class="mainmenu text-center floatleft">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a routerLink="/home" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>

          </li>

          <li><a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">about</a></li>


          <li>
            <a routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">contact</a>
          </li>


        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

below is my

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { HomesliderComponent } from './homeslider/homeslider.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  // { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  // { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],

  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [HomeComponent, AboutComponent, ContactComponent, NavigationComponent, HomesliderComponent, FooterComponent];
```

Apart from this i have included owl-caurousel code on home-component.html page,i haven't used  owl-caurousel npm

included all supporting css and js files in angular-cli.json

```
   "styles": [
      "styles.css",
      "assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css",
      "assets/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css",
      "assets/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css",
      "assets/template/tabcontent.css",
      "assets/threeDslider/css/threeDstyles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js",
      "assets/owl-carousel/slider.js",
      "assets/threeDslider/js/modernizr.custom.53451.js"


    ],
```

Please suggest me any solution, any tutorial on creating a static website using angular 5 or some thing like this also will be helpful
already googled and finally posting here
Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I think first you need to add your component in `declarations:[]` no need to create `export const routingComponents:[]` and also no need to `exports: [RouterModule]` because your are import router module for appModule

Comment: Already declared in app-module.ts 

as routingComponents in declarations.. 

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: you need add all created components in `declarations:[]` and add **RoutingModule** in  `imports: []`

Comment: You can also check your js file is load or not. on the time of component loading.

Comment: Hi, i have included in declarations but still slider not loading ,it is loading only on page refresh..is there any way to include slider ..
i have gone through this link also [ https://github.com/admister/angular-6-website ]
but in that there is no slider

but in that author included gallery module, any that type of work around much appreciated